# theme does not apply to checkbox items in listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest, android-theme, android-checkbox

I am applying a color theme to my widgets in my application through http://android-holo-colors.com/ but the items in my ListView does not follow the color theme. I tried creating a simple CheckBox item outside of my ListView, my color theme which is green is applied to the single CheckBox outside of my ListView. My color theme used to be working on the items in my ListView, I just recently noticed that it stopped working but I haven't made any changes to my AppTheme.

The screenshot below shows that my color them is only applied to the first CheckBox which outside the ListView, but the items on my ListView does not apply my color theme on the CheckBox

[image]

Below is my BaseAdapter on setting the CheckBox items in my ListView

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.subject_row, null);

    CheckBox textRow = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subject);
    textRow.setText(getItem(position));

    textRow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (v instanceof CheckBox) {

                String subject = ((CheckBox) v).getText().toString();
                Log.i("subject", subject);

                if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                    activity.arrayListSelectedSubject.add(subject);
                }

                try {
                    if (!((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                        activity.arrayListSelectedSubject
                                .remove(activity.arrayListSelectedSubject
                                        .indexOf(subject));

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("catch Exception", String.valueOf(e));
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }// end try-catch

            }// end if (v instanceof CheckBox)

            Log.i("selectedSubjectArrayList", String
                    .valueOf(activity.arrayListSelectedSubject.size()));

        }// end onClick
    });// end setOnClickListener

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: You should post the theme you used.

Comment: Do you mean styles_apptheme.xml file in my values folder or my manifest.xml file? I just copied the res folder generated from http://android-holo-colors.com/ I wonder why the color theme is applied to the single CheckBox that is outside of my ListView but the CheckBox items inside of my ListView does not apply the same color theme.

Comment: To which `Context` does the `this.context` variable point to(`Activity` `Context` or `Context` retrieve through `getApplicationContext()`)?

Comment: I got it from the constructor of my BaseAdapter. this.context = activity.getApplicationContext(); where activity refers to my FragmentActivity.

Comment: Use the `Activity` as the `Context`:  `this.context = activity;`.

Comment: By the way, the ActionBar menu you see above which is on the upper right also does not follow the color theme I applied. If you could also help me with that. Appreciate it much.

Comment: Post a new question. The generator you link to will only style view widgets it doesn't affect menu icons. You'll need to build them yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `activity.this` as your context, not `getApplicationContext()`.

Answer (score 0):

I also have this problem. 
Try to use the ViewGroup parent of getView function to get the correct context.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext()
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```